# Obtener todas las combinaciones de un grafo acíclico dirigido

Tags: r

Vuelvo a formular la pregunta ya que no fui capaz de explicarla con exactitud. Necesito obtener todas las combinaciones posibles de un grafo acíclico dirigido.

```
adjacency_matrix <- read.table(text = "A B C D
A   0   0   1   0
B   0   0   1   0
C   0   0   0   1
D   0   0   0   0", header = TRUE)
```

A partir de la matriz de adyacencia obtengo el siguiente grafo:

[image: Graph]

Cuantas combinaciones puede obtener con `n=4`? `2^4=16`

```
solution <- expand.grid(rep(list(c(1, 0)), 4))
colnames(solution) <- c("A","B","C","D")

    A    B    C    D
1   1    1    1    1
2   0    1    1    1
3   1    0    1    1
4   0    0    1    1
5   1    1    0    1
6   0    1    0    1
7   1    0    0    1
8   0    0    0    1
9   1    1    1    0
10  0    1    1    0
11  1    0    1    0
12  0    0    1    0
13  1    1    0    0
14  0    1    0    0
15  1    0    0    0
16  0    0    0    0
```

Todas las combinaciones son factibles? No, porque al ser un grafo dirigido para que un nodo esté en la soluciones deben de estar su predecesores.

```
    A    B    C    D
1   1    1    1    1 #APTA
2   0    1    1    1 #NO APTA, para escoger C, todos sus predecesores deben de estar en la solución: A y B
3   1    0    1    1 #NO APTA, para escoger C, deben de estar A y B
4   0    0    1    1 #NO APTA, para escoger C, deben de estar A y B, para esoger D deben de estar: A, B y C
5   1    1    0    1 #NO APTA, para escoger D, deben de estar C y todos sus predecesores 
6   0    1    0    1 #NO APTA, para escoger D, deben de estar C y todos sus predecesores 
7   1    0    0    1 #NO APTA, para escoger D, deben de estar C y todos sus predecesores 
8   0    0    0    1 #NO APTA, para escoger D, deben de estar C y todos sus predecesores 
9   1    1    1    0 #APTA
10  0    1    1    0 #NO APTA, para escoger C, deben de estar todos sus predecesores
11  1    0    1    0 #NO APTA, para escoger C, deben de estar todos sus predecesores
12  0    0    1    0 #NO APTA, para escoger C, deben de estar todos sus predecesores 
13  1    1    0    0 #APTA
14  0    1    0    0 #APTA
15  1    0    0    0 #APTA
16  0    0    0    0 #APTA
```

Así que de `16` combinaciones me quedaría con `6`:

```
    A    B    C    D
1   1    1    1    1 #APTA
9   1    1    1    0 #APTA
13  1    1    0    0 #APTA
14  0    1    0    0 #APTA
15  1    0    0    0 #APTA
16  0    0    0    0 #APTA
```

También estoy intentando evitar crear todas las combinaciones previamente, ya que con grafos de 5 y 20 nodos son factibles, pero cuando hablamos de 50 y 100 el tiempo crece exponencialmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Ahora si me quedó claro). En primer lugar necesitamos el objeto `network` para empezar a trabajar:

```
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(adjacency_matrix), 
                                       mode = "directed")
```

Lo que se puede hacer es:

1. Obtener los lista de nodos hijo/padre completa mediante `get.edgelist()`
2. Iterar sobre cada combinación / fila de `solution`
3. Si todos los padres que le corresponden a cada nodo están en la selección, o todos los nodos no tienen "padres", entonces será una solución válida.

Revisemos primero, lo que nos retorna `get.edgelist()`:

```
get.edgelist(network)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "C" 
[2,] "B"  "C" 
[3,] "C"  "D"
```

En la segunda columna tenemos los nodos "hijos" y en la primera el "padre". Y ahora, vamos a crear un `closure` o una `function factory`, simplemente a efectos de hacer más performante y elegante la función final.

```
make_is_valid_function <- function(network, solution) {

    elist <- get.edgelist(network)
    nodos <- colnames(solution) 

    f <- function(row) {

        padres <- c() 
        seleccion <- nodos[which(row == 1)]
        for (nodo in seleccion) {
            padres <- c(padres, elist[elist[,2] == nodo, 1])
        }
        return(all(padres %in% seleccion) || length(padres) == 0)
    }
    return(f)
}
```

Lo importante es lo que define la función interna `f()`: (a) recibe una combinación, (b) se queda con los nodos seleccionados (c) obtiene los padres de estos (d) verifica si estos ya se encuentran en la selección

Ahora podemos fabricar la función que usaremos:

```
is_valid <- make_is_valid_function(network, solution)
```

En este caso `is_valid` es una función dinamicamente fabricada, para trabajar con los objetos `network` y `solution` y que espera un vector con la combinación a analizar. Por lo que únicamente resta hacer:

```
cbind(solution, valida=apply(solution, MARGIN=1, FUN = is_valid))

   A B C D valida
1  1 1 1 1   TRUE
2  0 1 1 1  FALSE
3  1 0 1 1  FALSE
4  0 0 1 1  FALSE
5  1 1 0 1  FALSE
6  0 1 0 1  FALSE
7  1 0 0 1  FALSE
8  0 0 0 1  FALSE
9  1 1 1 0   TRUE
10 0 1 1 0  FALSE
11 1 0 1 0  FALSE
12 0 0 1 0  FALSE
13 1 1 0 0   TRUE
14 0 1 0 0   TRUE
15 1 0 0 0   TRUE
16 0 0 0 0   TRUE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, es justo lo que buscaba. Una pregunta, ¿crees que hay alguna forma de extraer todas las combinaciones correctas sin generar previamente todas las combinaciones posibles? Saludos.

Comment: @Draggluon, no conozco en profundidad `igraph`, es muy completa y no me extrañaría que tenga alguna función para calcular esto.